# WordPress site seems convinced that it's still at its old URL

Tags: database, site-url

I had a demo environment set up in `/subdirectory/` and then moved it to my root directory to make the site live.

- Used the wp migrate db plugin to export my database with the new paths, then replaced all the database tables with my new export.
- I did a search and replace in PHPmyAdmin and replaced `/subdirectory` with `/`, just to make sure nothing was missed.
- *Copied* all the content from `/subdirectory` to my the site's root

Upon doing this, my site worked at the root URL, however, I noticed that the `bloginfo('template_directory');` and `get_template_directory_uri();` functions get the old URL! (`/subdirectory/wp-content/themes/my-theme/`).

If I remove the `/subdirectory/` files, the site doesn't load (I just see a blank page).

I went to my `index.php` to check on where `wp-blog-heaer.php` was being loaded from, making sure that it was referencing my root directory.

I also added

```
update_option('siteurl', 'http://www.mysite.com' );
update_option('home', 'http://www.mysite.com' );
```

to both wp-config files.

I even used the [Search and Replace Database Script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) recommended in the Wordpress Codex to make sure I didn't miss anything in the database like serialized strings.

Can't decipher why my site still thinks that it's in the old URL. Any ideas?

*edit:* My root .htaccess seems fine also. No mention of /subdirectory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess?

Comment: Just checked my root .htaccess, nothing in there that points to my subdirectory (added to my question).

Comment: ___Both___ `wp-config` files?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that! I just checked both wp-configs and found the issue. Will post it in an answer, but basically I overlooked a define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR' line. DERP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part,

At some point I defined my wp-content directories right in wp-config.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/home/user/public_html/site/subdirectory/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.seocial.ly/site/subdirectory/wp-content' );
```

Completely overlooked this when editing my wp-config.